# In a column of flex items, place the last two items in a single row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Without modifying the HTML or using some `position: absolute` hackery, is it possible to make items 6 and 7 in this list appear side-by-side on row 6?

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/511qb3py/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method:

- Switch the `flex-direction` to `row`.
- Enable `wrap`.
- Give each flex item enough width so that only one can fit on a line. This forces the following items to create new lines.
- Give the last two items (6 and 7) a width that enables both to fit on one line.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
li {
  flex: 0 0 66%; /* flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis */
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
li:nth-last-child(-n + 2) {
  flex-basis: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  min-width: 33%;
  max-width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 100%;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
li:nth-last-child(-n + 2) {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```