# How do I make this layout with flexbox?

Tags: css, web, flexbox

I've got a form with a couple areas to it and I've been trying to figure out how to get flexbox to lay something out like this:

[image: Desired Design]

If possible, how could I do this while using the least amount of parent containers? (Or, why might I not want to do that?)

Stumped enough by not having achieved this that I think asking is the right move. Still wrapping my head around it all.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40011471/3597276

Comment: modified demo from the duplicate: https://jsfiddle.net/0w8mv3n4/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;  
  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside { flex: 1 auto; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main    { flex: 3 0px; }
  .aside-1 { order: 1; } 
  .main    { order: 2; }
  .aside-2 { order: 3; }
  .footer  { order: 4; }
}

body {
  padding: 2em; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
  <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Modified from an example found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Full credit to css-tricks.

Edit: highly recommend that css-tricks article. Very helpful resource for all things flexbox

Comment: I have to wait ~10 mins to mark this as the correct answer, but it obviously is. Thank you!

What's that   flex: 1 100%; in the .wrapper children do?

Comment: That is the shorthand for setting the flex-grow and flex-shrink to 1, and the flex-basis to 100%. Some people prefer the shorthand, but I personally think its difficult to follow because if it had been `flex: 1 2` it would actually be setting only the grow/shrink (because 2 is a unitless number, whereas 100% is technically not)

Answer (score 0):

you can build this layout from body with a few CSS lines:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;/* or 100vw just for body */
  margin:0 /* reset */
}

body,
section {
  display: flex;
}
/* eventually : section {overflow:auto} if you want to keep footer down the screen no matter how much content */
body {
  flex-flow: column;
}
section,
article {
  flex: 1;/* use whole space avalaible if only child or share it evenly when multiple children */
}
/* add borders to see elements */
header,
footer,
article {
  border: solid;
  padding: 1em;
}

/* break point  without mediaqueries ? 
uncomment this below */
/* article {
  min-width:320px;/* 2 articles make break point at average 640px */
}*/
```

```html
<header>
  header any height
</header>
<section>
  <article>Side</article>
  <article>Side</article>
</section>
<footer>
  footer any height
</footer>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WGazGX to play with ([or download code samples](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/share/zip/WGazGX/))